# Вложенные структуры С++

Tags: c++, структуры

Столкнулся я с проблемой вложенных структур, а проблема заключается вот в чем:

```
struct first
{
    int one,two,three;
    struct second structvar; /// Не принимает 
       // (слышал можно не писать struct 
       //  при объявлении структурной переменной, так ведь?), 
       // наверно из-за того что второй структуры в памяти компилятора нет
};

struct second
{
    char text[100],text2[100],text3[100];
};
```

Нужно что-то вроде прототипа функции, но для структуры, не хочется просто менять структуры местами, а изначально определять их как вложенные тоже не хочу(просто допустим у меня много структур написанных отдельно, хотелось бы допустим пару строк вписать и получилась вложенная структура)

Comment: компилятор должен знать размер поля structvar.
Forward-declaration можно использовать только для указателей и ссылок.

Answer (score 3):

`struct` нужно обязательно писать только в C. Или использовать `typedef`. В плюсах писать `struct` не обязательно (но только когда объявляется переменная типа структура, а не сама структура). Структуру можно объявить позже,  но в ее использовании выше нужно использовать указатель на структуру и выше написать что то вида `struct second;`

Поэтому, правильная идея - разместить все структуры правильно.

Comment: как должна выглядеть структура если допустим house.stage.apartment(выдает номер квартиры), а house.stage(номер этажа) ?
Просто такое частенько вижу, а как выглядит такая структура - непонятно

Comment: Найти программиста за деньги. Наберите это в гугле, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: я не прошу писать сложную структуру, так просто какой-нибудь простенький пример, в обучающем плане, я же не требую написать за меня код

Comment: @MaximPro - можно много чего сделать. Если где то видели красивое решение - смотрите сорцы. Если решение видели, но не поняли - создавайте новый вопрос, прикладывайте ссылку на исходники. Если только видели код, но не понимаете, как это сделано "внутри" - создавайте вопрос, где приведите пример того, как хочется использовать, а можно ли так сделать и как именно - уже будет в ответах.